# Capturar valor del JTextField y reproducir .wav

Tags: java

[EDIT]
Carpeta:
[image: carpeta]
Necesito capturar el valor del JTextField para así reproducir cualquier cancion de este programa. Por el momento, al darle al botón Play, reproduce la canción que le pongo ahí, lo que yo quiero hacer es darle el nombre de una canción al JTextField(que tenga guardada)  y de ahí reproducirla, pero no puedo.

agradecería si me ayudan.

CODIGO:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Audio3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    private File songFile;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private Clip clip;
    private JButton bPlay, bStop;
    private JPanel panel1, panel2;
    private JTextField tfCancion;

    public Audio3() throws Exception 
    {
        super("Audio TEC");
        tfCancion = new JTextField();
        bPlay = new JButton("Play");
        bStop = new JButton("Stop");
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2= new JPanel();


        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel1.add(new JLabel("Song: "));
        panel1.add(tfCancion);
        panel1.add(bPlay);
        panel1.add(bStop);
        panel2.add(panel1);
        add(panel2);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,300);

        reproducir();



    }


    public Audio3(String song) throws Exception 
    {
        super("Audio TEC");

        tfCancion= new JTextField();
        bPlay = new JButton("Reproducir");
        bStop = new JButton("Stop");
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();

        bPlay.addActionListener(this);
        bStop.addActionListener(this);
        tfCancion.addActionListener(this);

        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Cancion"));
        panel1.add(tfCancion);
        panel1.add(bPlay);
        panel1.add(bStop);

        panel2.add(panel1);
        add(panel2);


        reproducir(song);

        setSize(400,300);
        setVisible(true);

    } 




    private void reproducir() throws Exception 
    {
        // 1. Obtener el nombre de la cancion a reproducir
        String song =("Hotel California.wav");

        // 2. Relacionar el nombre de la cancion con un Archivo (File) wav
        songFile = new File(song);
        // 3. Preparar el Audio Stream del archivo de la cancion 
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songFile);

        // 4. Reproducir

        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
    //  while(true)
    //  clip.start();
    }

    private void reproducir(String song) throws Exception 
    {
        // 1. Obtener el nombre de la cancion a reproducir
    //  String song = "Last_Nite.wav";

        // 2. Relacionar el nombre de la cancion con un Archivo (File) wav
        songFile = new File(song);
        // 3. Preparar el Audio Stream del archivo de la cancion 
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songFile);

        // 4. Reproducir

        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
    //  while(true)
    //      clip.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == bPlay)
        {
            clip.start();
        }
        if(e.getSource() == bStop)
        {
            clip.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        //Audio3 audio = new Audio3();
        Audio3 audio = new Audio3("Hotel California.wav");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no está bien organizado, tenes mucho código duplicado, no voy a entrar en detalles de cómo podes mejorarlo, así que te recomiendo revisarlo, te podes guiar por [esta presentación](https://www.slideshare.net/kindblad/avoid-code-duplication-principles-patterns) para entender a qué me refiero.

En cuánto al código, modifica tu `actionPerformed` para que llame a tu método reproducir, así:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == bPlay)
    {
        //clip.start();
        try {
            reproducir(tfCancion.getText());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == bStop)
    { //hacer stop
        clip.stop();
    }
}
```

[Respuesta original]
Si tu `JTextField` almacena la ruta del archivo (como estoy suponiendo), debes reemplazar esta línea

```
String song =("Hotel California.wav");
```

Por esta línea:

```
String song = tfCancion.getText();
```

La documentación del método [JTextComponent.getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) como referencia.

[Edición]
Es probable que sea más conveniente al usuario permitir seleccionar el archivo, podes usar lo siguiente como base:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "Archivos WAV", "wav");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this); //this se referiría al JFrame principal
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String ruta = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        //usar la ruta
        tfCancion.setText(ruta);
}
```

El código anterior usa entre otras cosas un [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog(java.awt.Component)), un tutorial más o menos completo de cómo usar este componente lo encontras en el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: Hice eso, Compilo, pero al ejecutarlo:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

Comment: Tenes que asegurarte que el archivo exista, probablemente en lugar de usar el JTextField te sale mejor usar un JFileChooser. Ve mi respuesta editada.

Comment: Si, tengo mis .wav en la misma carpeta que Audio3.java . Podría usar el JFileChooser, pero así no me lo piden :(

Comment: Asegurate que los archivos estén en la misma carpeta donde está tu .class no donde esta tu .java. Por lo general los IDEs (si estás usando uno) ponen los archivos compilados en una carpeta distinta (eso depende de cómo tengas configurado tu proyecto)

Comment: Si, mi .class igual esta en la misma carpeta.

Comment: ¿podrías editar la pregunta con un screenshot del contenido de la carpeta donde están los archivos y un screenshot del valor que usas para el nombre del archivo?

Comment: Listo, los demás son otros programas simples que no tienen que ver con el que el que estoy trabajando(Audio3) y no sé a que te refieras  con los valores de archivo.

Comment: ¿qué valor usas para el archivo al momento de darle play?

Comment: Creo que ninguno, solo le doy una acción al botón play o no te estoy entendiendo

Comment: Hola, creo que el código que muestras tiene dos e errores: 1. Le agregas al TextField el escuchador para el evento clic, cosa que veo innecesario. 2. El método reproducir(String song) solo se ejecutara una vez y los botones lo único que hacen es reproducir y pausar el mismo tema.

Comment: El problema es que haces una llamada a reproducir al momento de construir el JFrame en el main haces un new Audio3(...), el cual llama a reproducir, si cambiaste la línea para que use el valor del textfield al momento de ejecutarse ese valor estará en "" y por ende el archivo no existirá.

Comment: Mmm entonces tengo que llamar el metodo reproducir(String) con el texto del JTextField antes de llamar clip.start() ?. No entiendo mucho, soy algo novato en java :'(